# Proof of scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra

i need help with proof. Why $\langle AA^Ti,i\rangle \ge \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i^2$, where $i$ is vector of $m$ ones, $A$ is $m \times n $ matrix, $A^T$ is transpose matrix and $c_i$ is sum of elements of $i$-th column matrix $A$.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be the $m\times1$ column vector with a $1$ at each entry.

Now, in order to obtain the $j$-th entry of the $n\times 1$ column vector $A^tx$, we compute the dot product between the $j$-th row of $A^t$ with $x$, right?  Also, the $j$-th row of $A^t$ is the same as the $j$-th column of $A$, and compute the dot product between some vector $y$ with a vector of only ones is just addem up the entries of $y$.

So, $A^tx$ looks like
$$
A^tx = 
\begin{pmatrix}
c_1 \\ c_2 \\ \vdots \\ c_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and hence
$$
\langle AA^tx,x \rangle = \langle A^tx,A^tx \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2.
$$

Comment: thank you very much, but i have one more question (probably stupid), why $\langle AA^tx,x \rangle=\langle A^tx,A^tx \rangle$?

Comment: You can think about as follows : $$\begin{align} \langle Ax,y \rangle &= y^t(Ax) \\ &= (y^tA)x \\ &= (A^ty)^tx \\ &= \langle x,A^ty \rangle \end{align}$$ that is, we can view this equation by shifting the $A$ inside the inner product and adding the transpose.